# Howto cancel a delayed DOM element removal

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

I am trying to remove a DOM element after a delay. I also wish to cancel this removal with a user click (if they click before the timer expires. This is what I have:

`<div class="delete">Delete me!</div>`

Obviously, I am only showing the relevant source.

```
$("div.delete").click(function() {
    var element = $(this),
        timeout = element.attr('data-timeout');
    if (timeout) {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        element.removeAttr('data-timeout');
        element.text("Delete me!");
    } else {
        timeout = setTimeout(function() {
            element.remove();
            alert('Sniff, too late!');
        }, 2000);
        element.attr('data-timeout', timeout);
        element.text("Save me!");
    }
});
```

This works! My questions

1. Is there a better way? My first failed try had mutiple handlers.
2. Why doesn't it work in Javascript 1.7?

http://jsfiddle.net/zhon/H8a9J/

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't work with JavaScript 1.7 because the browser you are using doesn't support it and/or or the way how it's embedded. Your fiddle works fine with Firefox.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_layout_engines_%28ECMAScript%29

Answer (score 2):

You need to define `timeout` outside of your handler.

```
var timeout;
$("div.delete").click(function() {
    var element = $(this);
    if (timeout) {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = undefined;
        element.text("Delete me!");
    } else {
        timeout = setTimeout(function() {
            element.remove();
            alert('Sniff, too late!');
        }, 2000);
        element.text("Save me!");
    }
});
```

I'd recommend enclosing the code to add handlers within some other function to avoid muddying the global namespace with timeout ids.

Comment: Uh, that's exactly what I said.

Comment: You just did what you told me NOT to do.

Comment: Ok, if that's the case, care to explain?

Comment: +1. To clarify a point for the OP: JS 1.7 (and JS strict-mode in older versions) doesn't allow the declaration of globals via `var`-less variable declaration. Instead, you must explicitly define `timeout` using `var` in the exact scope you need it.

Comment: @Diodeus There is a difference between "define a variable globally" and "define a variable in the next outer scope"; I imagine that is the the point saml is refering to.

Comment: @apsillers exactly what I was referring to.

Comment: Well said aspillers, but in the given example, it does amount to the same thing.

Comment: This doesn't even matter, the issue has nothing to do with the code, but with the javascript version being 1.7

Comment: My bad, in the example I left off the surrounding `jQuery(function () { ... });`

Comment: @saml, if I have mutiple `<div class='delete'>` your solution will only cancel the last delete.

Comment: It doesn't if you encapsulate your `timeout` var properly.

Answer (score -2):

Make `timeout` a global, and clear it on the user click.

```
clearTimeout(timeout);
```

Comment: Don't suggest making variables global!